# SharePoint 2013 JS Automatically Generate and Send Email on New Item Form Save

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, html, calculated-column-formula

Here is a screenshot containing the references below:
[image]

**BACKGROUND** (the numbers correspond with the items in the screenshot)

1. The 'Add New Item' button is pressed, which causes the 'New Item Form' Modal box to appear
2. The New Item Form Modal Box
3. Save New Item
4. HTML Image hyperlink, which generates an email and populates the Mail To, Subject, and Body fields

   - To: Josh@whokilledlaurapalmertechsupport.com
   - Subject: Text String
   - Body: 'Title' field value

Calculated column for HTML button (4):

`="<a href=""Josh@whokilledlaurapalmertechsupport.com"&"?Subject="&joshTextString&"&Body="&Title&""" target=_top>"&"<img src=../SiteAssets/ICONS/sent.png style=height:20px;width:20px;/>"&"</a>"`

5. Send button on the automatically generated email

**QUESTION**

Once the new record is saved, I'd like an email corresponding with that
new item to be automatically generated and sent. I 'd prefer not to create a WF for this, because the recipient is an external user.

Is it possible to create a script to run once (3) is pressed by the USER and the record is CREATED and SAVED, which will automatically click (4) for that new item, generating a new email, and once it's generated, automatically click (5) and send the email? I don't have a button ID, because the button is not in js.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking (4) might be possible with javascript and hooking into events (closing the modal window of the new item form, for example), but clicking (5) is not. You can't control the click action in Outlook using javascript executing in a browser.

Comment: Appreciate the info -- what would you suggest as a good workaround? I was hoping to avoid using a 2010 workflow to send the email to an external user.

Comment: You can write a desktop application that uses CSOM to create the new list item and send the email to your SMTP server.  Not a great solution - but it'd work. You'd need to create your Add New Item form in your desktop app and inform your users that they are NOT to use the browser to add these items.

Comment: That's a smart fix, thanks. I am going to go with your original suggestion at stop at (4). If the button is an html button, what's the best way to hook it to the closing of the modal window? I don't expect you to solve this for me, but if you could point me in the right direction (online source) I'd be very appreciative. Thanks again for your help.